# How can I simplify this fraction problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the problem $\frac{x^2}{x^2-4} - \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ which should simplify to $\frac{1}{x-2}$

I have simplified $x^2-4$, which becomes:

$\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)} - \frac{x+1}{x+2}$

However, if I combine the fractions I get, $x^2-x-1$ for the numerator, which can't be factored. That's where I get stuck.

How can I get $\frac{1}{x-2}$ out of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put them over a common denominator,
$$\frac {x+1}{x+2}=\frac {(x+1)(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=\frac {x^2-x-2}{x^2-4}$$
Now you can subtract the numerators
$$x^2-(x^2-x-2)=x+2$$
and finally divide out the $x+2$ from numerator and denominator

Your $-1$ should be $-2$.  You didn't show your work, so I can't see why it happened.

Comment: Regarding your last line, I wonder if OP just added the two numerators together without finding a common denominator.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That's right. It's been awhile since I worked with fractions, and I'm very rusty.

Comment: @LuminousNutria It's a very common error.  But if you think about it with familiar fractions you'll remember it can't be true.  For instance, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ is $1$, not $\frac{2}{4}$ (which is $\frac{1}{2}$ again).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)} - \frac{x+1}{x+2}&=\frac1{x+2}\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2} - (x+1)\right)\\
&=\frac1{x+2}\left(\frac{x^2-(x-2)(x+1)}{x-2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{x+2}\left(\frac{x^2-(x^2-x-2)}{x-2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{x+2}\left(\frac{x+2}{x-2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{x-2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)}-\frac{x+1}{x+2}=\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)}-\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=…$$
Note that it must be $$x\ne 2,-2$$

Answer (score 0):

The numerator should be
$$x^2-(x-2)(x+1) = x+2$$
which simplifies with a factor of the denominator.

You probably just forgot a term when subtracting the two fractions.